# Considering numpy matrix row independent of other rows while performing softmax computation

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

This is rather noob question. I am trying to code the neural network from scratch.
This is how I have wrote the softmax function:

```
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()
```

Then I created a dummy weights matrix:

```
w0 = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (6, 4))
print(w0.shape)
print(w0)
```

This prints:

```
(6, 4)
array([[-0.47349099, -0.56027454,  0.78373698, -0.23283302],
       [-0.63164942, -0.23417482,  0.00111565,  0.22848594],
       [-0.41288949,  0.05927629, -0.59752415,  0.45548192],
       [-0.35111661,  0.13681976, -0.73963359,  0.53842663],
       [-0.58055457, -0.03494196,  0.59678369, -0.40245336],
       [ 0.57615495, -0.03258459, -0.25033765,  0.20835347]])
```

These are weights of 4 classes (output labels) across 6 training examples. I want softmax probabilities to be calculated for each label for all training examples. So, I tried something like this:

```
sft = softmax(w0) # calculating softmax for all 6 training examples
print(sft.shape)
print(sft)
softmax(w0[0]) # calculating softmax for only 1st training example
```

This prints:

```
(6, 4)
[[0.02550981 0.02338932 0.08968387 0.03245067]  # <-- 1
 [0.02177809 0.03240715 0.041004   0.0514721 ]
 [0.02710354 0.04345954 0.0225341  0.06458847]
 [0.0288306  0.04696364 0.01954893 0.07017419]
 [0.02291976 0.03955183 0.0743912  0.02738788]
 [0.07287233 0.03964518 0.03188757 0.0504462 ]]
array([0.1491508 , 0.13675272, 0.52436386, 0.18973262]) # <-- 2
```

I felt that the first row in the `sft` matrix should be same as the last the output of `softmax(w0[0])`. That is line suffixed `<-- 1` should be same as `<-- 2` as both correspond to same training example. But it seems that `softmax(w0)` is calculating probabilities across whole matrix considering it as single training example and not interpreting each row as separate training example.

How to do softmax computation interpreting each row independent of others? What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e_x.sum()` and `np.max(x)` will, by default be applied over the full matrix, returning a scalar.
You can check this by looking at the difference between

```py
>>> np.max(w0)
0.78373698
>>> np.max(w0, axis=1)
array([0.78373698, 0.22848594, 0.45548192, 0.53842663, 0.59678369,
       0.57615495])
```

for instance.
You probably want to run this over every rows, which you can do using the `axis` argument:

```py
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=1)
```

However, if you do this you will have broadcasting issues. Numpy doesn't know how to handle the operation

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] - [7,8,9]
```

To keep the dimensions correct, you can use the `keepdims` argument:

```py
>>> np.max(w0, axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[0.78373698],
       [0.22848594],
       [0.45548192],
       [0.53842663],
       [0.59678369],
       [0.57615495]])
```

Now, applying all of that, you can should be able to use:

```py
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

and, get this result:

```
>>> print(softmax(w0))
[[0.1491508  0.13675272 0.52436386 0.18973262]
 [0.14849238 0.22096587 0.27958287 0.35095887]
 [0.17188339 0.27560869 0.14290522 0.40960271]
 [0.17418476 0.28373847 0.11810801 0.42396877]
 [0.13954134 0.24080164 0.45291261 0.16674441]
 [0.37398946 0.2034638  0.16365082 0.25889592]]
>>> print(softmax([w0[0]]))
[[0.1491508  0.13675272 0.52436386 0.18973262]]
```

(Notice that now, softmax expects a 2D-array, so I had to encapsulate the single row in an array)
*Edit*: to generalise the input that the `softmax` function can take, you can do some shape checks:

```py
def softmax(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    if len(x.shape) == 1:
        x = x.reshape(1,-1)
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

for instance. The `reshape` will add a dimension, similarly to having `[x]` instead of `x`.
The more assumptions you make on the input data, the less checks you have to make, the more efficient your function will be!
For instance, I also added a check, in case the data is a list, to make it an array, but if it's not needed, you can remove it for performance improvement

Comment: This is perfect! Just guessing if we can generalise this. That is, doing away with need to wrap `w0[0]` inside list. I tried setting `axis=1 if len(w0.shape)>1 else 0` at both places. But it did gave error `axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1` for `e_x` calculation row.

Comment: Edited my answer with more details for that! :)

Comment: Some general doubts: do we usually deal with these subtleties while preparing ML model? If yes, then how should we be proficient at these? By practising by doing more ML projects? Apart from `keepdims` and `axis`, what other parameters of other functions are important? (Last question might be unrealistic to answer as there can be a lot of them. But I dont want exhaustive list. May be 4/5 parameters that come at top of your head. Or better some pre-made list or doc page that warn of possible subtle things regarding such arguments to remember to avoid mistakes. This will give me a direction.)

Comment: If you want to code everything from scratch, then yes, you will have to deal with nitty-gritty details. Usually, you will however let libraries take care of this for you. For instance [pytorch's softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html), they take care of the dimensions, data type, and running operations on GPU when needed